# Draw simple lines on canvas using Mouse Cursor just as MS paint does (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone help me to draw lines on a canvas implementing mouse cursor move and click event?

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037753/wpf-drawing-on-canvas-with-mouse-events

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the [InkCanvas Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx).