# Trying to implement Polyline in WPF C# but throws 'Specified Visual is already a child' error

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, polyline

I am trying to implement a `Polyline`following this: [WPF Drawing on Canvas with Mouse Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037753/wpf-drawing-on-canvas-with-mouse-events)/ Just like in the original query I successfully implemented the solution line draw but noticed a choppyness of the line. The next solution suggested that the problem was solved using Polyline. However, it's throwing the dreaded, "Specified Visual is already a child' error. These are the relevant code snippets:

```
        private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
        StartingPoint = currentPoint;

        if (ActiveDrawingTool == DRAW_ROADS)
        {
            polygonPoints = new PointCollection();
            polyLine = new Polyline();
        }
```

// etc...

```
 private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && ActiveDrawingTool != 0
            && ActiveDrawingTool != DRAW_PLACENAMES)
        {
            if (ActiveDrawingTool == DRAW_ROADS)
            {

                polyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                polyLine.StrokeThickness = 8;
                Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
                polygonPoints.Add(currentPoint);
                polyLine.Points = polygonPoints;
                MainCanvas.Children.Add(polyLine);

            }
```

The error is thrown on adding the polyline to the MainCanvas. Curiously, if I don't use a polyline it doesn't throw this error. I am trying to draw a continuous line in real-time using a polyline.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `polyLine` is already a child of `MainCanvas`. You can't add it twice. If you've added it once, do not call `Add(polyLine)` again. Or remove it before adding it again. Or create a new Polyline.

Comment: Okay, but I want to continuously draw the line as the mouse moves. The only place I can think of putting the call is in Canvas_MouseMove_1. How do I handle this? SOLVED IT... put the draw call in Canvas_MouseDown...thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens answered in comments, above:

> The error message is pretty clear. `polyLine` is already a child of `MainCanvas`. You can't add it twice. If you've added it once, do not call `Add(polyLine)` again. Or remove it before adding it again. Or create a new Polyline.

This solved the issue.